# List History of Indexes 

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to find out the history of when indexes were either rebuilt or reorganized in a database?  Basically is there a log file that contains this information?

Comment: Excellent blog post on using the default trace to audit SQL Server: http://sankarreddy.com/2010/04/t-sql-tuesday-005-who-put-my-database-offline/

Comment: I think this post may answer your question: 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831293/tsql-know-when-index-rebuild-reorg-or-updatestatistics-was-last-run-on-sql-ser][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831293/tsql-know-when-index-rebuild-reorg-or-updatestatistics-was-last-run-on-sql-ser

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can create a trigger that maintains such a log.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [YourDatabaseTrigger]
ON DATABASE
FOR DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS
AS

DECLARE @EventData      xml
DECLARE @Message        varchar(1000)
SET @EventData=EVENTDATA()

INSERT INTO YourLogTable 
    (EventDateTime,EventDescription) 
    VALUES (GETDATE(),SUSER_NAME()
                     +'; '+@EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectType)[1]', 'varchar(250)')
                     +'; '+@EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(250)')
                     +'; '+@EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
           )
RETURN
GO

ENABLE TRIGGER [YourDatabaseTrigger] ON DATABASE
```